# Proportional image scale-works in Firefox and Chrome but NOT in Safari

Tags: firefox, css, safari

Any CSS experts have a clue why this works fine in Firefox and latest Chrome, but NOT in Safari??
In Safari, as I reduce the width of the browser, the image scales horizontally, but not vertically and becomes 'squished'.

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 560px;
height: 100%;
max-height: 490px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `height: auto;` instead of `height: 100%;`. That way the height of the image will automatically be proportionate to the width based on its natural dimensions, even as the width changes.

Tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLqr9/1/